# Why isn't one of my javascript links working?

Tags: javascript, html

I have these javascript files in my project:

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--Game Script-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

The bottom one isn't working when I load up the page. Why might that be?

The html file and the script.js file are located in the same folder.

Look at the entire project here if you like: https://github.com/samjb2/IncrementalRPG. The document in question is game.html.

Comment: Try to call it without `type=''`. And make sure that it's in the same directory as your file you're calling it from.

Comment: What is the path of the page and where is your javascript file located?

Comment: @BeatAlex I've tried without 'type='. Same problem.

Comment: @JohnF. It is in the same folder as the html document.

Comment: This might sound stupid, but it happens. It's not called `script.js.js` is it?

Comment: Try using firebug to see what is happening to file when it loads. This could also be a loading issue in that the file might be executing but your logic isn't executing in the proper sequence. For example, do you need the page to be loaded before you perform any execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your jquery event click handlers inside of the

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// handlers go here
});
```

It seems like you need to wait for your page to load before you start attaching handlers to elements on your page. I moved them inside of $(document).ready() and I was able to click on "Chop Wood" and see it increment a value.

Comment: The game is running here http://samjb2.github.io/IncrementalRPG/game.html online.

Comment: @TrueVineCS I am able to see a dialog popup in the url. Are you not seeing the same? What is suppose to happen that isn't? I don't see any errors in the Firebug console.

Comment: The modal used the bootstrap.js, not script.js. Click on an orange button. The numbers next to it should go up. ('Chop Wood')

Comment: @TrueVineCS Ok. So the core issue is with the logic. Not that the script.js isn't loading.

Comment: @TrueVineCS Add the event handlers inside of the jquery $(document).ready();

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a shot in the dark here, because everything looks right. This is kind of one of those guesses where you look at things out of the corner of your eye and notice something that's not quite right. Or maybe I've been playing too much Phoenix Wright.

I submit that you are running your `game.html` file locally - that is, the URL in your browser's address bar looks like this:

> file:///C:/Users/Niet/Documents/game.html

In this case, your problem stems from this:

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The `//` resolves the address relative to the current *scheme*. In other words, it's looking for:

> file:///netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js

Needless to say, I'm pretty sure that file does not exist!

Try using this instead:

```
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

By explicitly stating the scheme, you avoid the problem of relative paths.

Alternatively, try running your game from a server, for example if you set one up on your computer you could try:

```
http://localhost/game.html
```

Again, if this works, I was right!

Comment: I tested your file and this is exactly what's happening.

Comment: The game is running on a Github page here: http://samjb2.github.io/IncrementalRPG/game.html but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and when the page loads up, watch the results.
I'm guessing you'll see a 404 not found error on the "script.js" request.

This is probably your problem, perhaps you should try `/script.js`, but it's hard to tell without knowing where your file is located.

Comment: "The html file and the script.js file are located in the same folder."

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol He wrote that after I answered. Nevertheless, watching Fiddler will provide him with the information he needs to fix this.